# Is there any way to Customize a year-text or label of a year picker which is created using react date picker library

Tags: reactjs, date, picker

My requirement is to create a financial date picker which has a year label or year text as 20-21 instead of 2020  and so on.I had gone through the react date picker docs, but I haven't found any prop to change the year.

The below is my code for year picker.

```
<DatePicker
  showIcon
  selected={selectedDate}
  onChange={handleYearChange}
  dateFormat="yyyy"
  showYearPicker
  className={classes.datepicker}
  placeholderText="yyyy"
  renderCustomHeader={renderCustomYearHeader}
  ref={calRef}
/>
```

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no direct way using a prop to change the year label or text in react date picker library, you can pass a custom header component to the `renderCustomHeader` prop.

Inside this custom component, you have access to the date being displayed, from which you can obtain the year, then apply any modifications to it.

Example:

```
const CustomYearHeader = ({ date, decreaseYear, increaseYear }) => {
  const year = new Date(date).getFullYear() % 100;
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={decreaseYear}>{"<"}</button>
      <span>{year}</span>
      <button onClick={increaseYear}>{">"}</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const FinancialDatePicker = ({ selectedDate, handleYearChange }) => {
  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={selectedDate}
      onChange={handleYearChange}
      dateFormat="yyyy"
      showYearPicker
      renderCustomHeader={CustomYearHeader}
      placeholderText="yyyy"
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks @tmilar .Using renderCustomHeader prop we can change header month and year that I understood but to change the year text of year picker cell do we have any props for that. Like 21-22 22-23 23-24 (first row) instead 2021 2022 and 2023.I tried renderDayContents prop but this works only on days not on years.